# Best way to source components

Tags: pcb-design

I'm fairly new to PCB design and I was wondering what the best step-by-step selection process is for component selection. I'm trying to create a battery-powered sensor with humidity, temperature and movement sensors. What steps can I undergo to find the best and most efficient components?

Comment: Start with your specifications. Then start looking for components that meet that specification. "*...  to find the best and most efficient components?*" That will result in over-expensive, over-engineered product. Find the lowest cost product that meets your specification.

Comment: To paraphrase, "best and most efficient" is the enemy of "good enough".

Comment: Make sure that the parts you choose are actually available.  I recall once finding a datasheet for a nice part for my application, then finding the part was never made!  Many parts are supposedly available in several different packages - again, check that the package you choose is actually available.

Comment: Is this for a personal or commercial application? How many are you planning to build?

Comment: I have an automotive background and have relied on three key standards which are IATF 16949, AEC-Q100 and AEC-Q200: If you take the time and read the specifications you will understand where I am coming from. These parts are not cheap however they are good and meet their specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the datasheets for the key components (also application notes and evaluation board documentation packs), chances are good that a reasonably competent engineer has already done much of the work for you and a reference design or "typical application" schematic is provided, perhaps with actual part recommendations for critical parts (such as the inductor in a switchmode supply).

To the degree you come up with something novel or modify the reference design, your understanding of component characteristics and non-technical factors may come into play. For example, I may choose a particular inductor because it is shielded, because it is easily available overnight  (or there's a reel sitting in the stock room), or because it is multiple-source and inexpensive for the PCBA house to source in Shenzhen. Maybe all factors are available at once, but more often there are trade-offs to be made.